# Can't setup mail externally zimbra 8.6

Tags: email-server, zimbra

I just setup zimbra 8.6 on ununtu 14 and have only one issue

I cannot setup mail externally

Here is mystery

Server host name is tin-exc-1.tingateitsolutions.com.au
Domain is tingateitsolutions.com.au
Mx record is mail.tingateitsolutions.com.au

I have no issue with mail flow and can get to webmail without issue by going to mail.tingateitsolutions.com.au

If I pu these details into outlook and put mail.tingateitsolutions.com.au as the http settings I get the prompt for my credentials but after that I get

The action cannot be completed. The connection to Microsoft exchange is unavailable. Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action

If someone could help me where I start so I can resolve it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect MS Outlook to Zimbra using MAPI then you need a Zimbra 8.6 **Network Edition** which requires a license. If you already have a Network Edition server then you want to install the Zimbra Outlok Connector to connect Outllok to Zimbra through MAPI.

[Admin doc](https://files.zimbra.com/website/docs/8.6/ZCS_Connector_for_Outlook_Admin_Guide_8.6.0.pdf)

[User doc](https://files.zimbra.com/website/docs/8.6/ZCS_Connector_for_Outlook_User_Guide_8.6.0.pdf)

If you want to use the open source version, then you can't use MAPI. You still can use IMAP and/or POP protocols.